# Function with another function as an optional argument

Tags: python, python-2.x, glob

I'm trying to write a function that takes another function as an optional argument. I'm a little stuck (and confused) with the syntax. I want func2 to be an optional argument. So I only want it to work when I call it in func1. I want it to work as a filter function for when I have more complex file patterns. `glob.glob(files + '/*')`can give all the files in the directories specified. `(glob.glob(path + '/' + file_name + '*'))` can give more complex patterns, I'm just not sure how to implement it as an optional function argument. any help would be much appreciated!

```
import glob

def func1(dirs, func2):

    if type(dirs) == list:
        for files in dirs:
            files = glob.glob(files + '/*')
            print(files) # prints all of the file names in each directory given
            if func2:
                func2(file_name)          



def func2(file_name):
    if file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
        # (glob.glob(path + '/' + file_name + '*'))

func1(['C:\path\to\files1\', 'C:\path\to\files2\'], func2('test2'))
```

For this example assume \files1 contains 'test1.txt' and 'test2.txt' and files2 containts 'test1.jpg' and 'test2.jpg'. I want `func1` to print the the path for test2.txt and test1.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is how you pass the function. You're currently passing the `return` of `func2('test2')`, you should just pass `func2`. Also be sure to pass `files` to func2, otherwise that won't be defined.

```
import glob

def func1(dirs, func2, another_variable):

    if type(dirs) == list:
        for files in dirs:
            files = glob.glob(files + '/*')
            print(files) # prints all of the file names in each directory given
            if func2:
                func2(another_variable, files)          



def func2(file_name, files):
    if file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
        # (glob.glob(path + '/' + file_name + '*'))

func1(['C:\path\to\files1\', 'C:\path\to\files2\'], func2, 'test_2')
```

Comment: But when I call func1 I want to look for the file named 'test2' - i don't think i'd be doing that with this implementation though?

Comment: Then you should add that as well as an added variable @says

Comment: Is there a way I can integrate them both so I'm calling func2 with the file name I'm looking for?

Comment: @says perhaps, I wouldn't know how though. I've updated my answer to reflect how I would pass 'test_2' as the file you want to check for using `another_variable`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your first function, use the optional argument type with a different name.

This will be sufficient to complete your code.

```
import glob

def func1(dirs, printer=False):

    if type(dirs) == list:
        for files in dirs:
            files = glob.glob(files + '/*')
            print(files) # prints all of the file names in each directory given
            if printer is True:
                func2(file_name)          



def func2(file_name):
    if file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
        # (glob.glob(path + '/' + file_name + '*'))

# EXECUTE WITHOUT FUNCTION CALLING FUNC2
func1(['C:\\path\\to\\files1\\', 'C:\\path\\to\\files2\\'])

# EXECUTE WITH FUNCTION CALLING FUNC2
func1(['C:\\path\\to\\files1\\', 'C:\\path\\to\\files2\\'],True)
```

Comment: But when I call func1 I want to look for the file named 'test2', so I need to specify that somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can delay the call to func2 by passing the parameter as a lambda

```
func1(['C:\\path\\to\\files1\\', 'C:\\path\\to\\files2\\'], lambda _ : func2('test2'))
```

or if you are using a different file name later

```
func1(['C:\\path\\to\\files1\\', 'C:\\path\\to\\files2\\'], lambda x : func2(x))
```

Comment: Thanks FonnParr, I'm not sure how I'd implement this in the rest of my code though? I've only ever used lambda functions for simple math calcs. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When your code finds func2('test') in your code, it tries to run this straight away and gives you the result, then passes that result on to the func1 call.

by putting lambda _ : on the front of this - it is saying that there is now an anonymous function (with the ignored  parameter _ ) that now calls this.

It is this anonymous lambda function that you are passing to func1 as the second parameter so it is only called when required.

On second thoughts - I have edited my answer to use the file name that you need later on

Comment: So from my original post, would I only need to change the function call. `func1(['C:\path\to\files1\', 'C:\path\to\files2\'], lambda 'test2' : func2('test2'))`?

Comment: That wouldn't quite work: 

try 

func1(['C:\path\to\files1\', 'C:\path\to\files2\'], lambda _ : func2('test2'))